# How would one create a Drupal-based Genealogy Application?

Tags: php, drupal-7, genealogy, gedcom

I want to use Drupal for building a Genealogy application.  The difficulty, I see, is in allowing users to upload a gedcom file and for it to be parsed and then from that data, various Drupal nodes would be created.  Nodes in Drupal are content items.  So, I'd have individuals and families as content types and each would have various events as fields that would come from the gedcom file.

The gedcom file is a generic format for genealogy information.  Different desktop applications take the data and convert it to a proprietary format.  What I am not sure about how to accomplish is to give the end user a form to upload their gedcom file and then have it create nodes, aka content items, with Drupal.  I can find open source code to parse a gedcom file, using python, or perl, or other languages.  So, I could use one of these libraries to create from the gedcom file output in JSON, XML, CSV, etc.

Drupal is written in PHP and another detail of the challenge is that for the end user, I don't want to ask him/her to find that file created in step one (where step one is the parse and convert of the gedcom file) and upload that into Drupal.  I'd like to somehow make this happen in one step as far as the end user sees.  Somehow I would need a way to trigger Drupal to import the data after it is converted into JSON, or XML or CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not personally familiar with Drupal. But I do know there already is a fairly advanced program written for Drupal called [Family Tree that is a project at Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/family).

You might want to check that project out, or even better, contribute to it and improve it.

Disclaimer:  I have no connection at all to the project, and I've never even tried the module. I just happen to be aware of it.

Comment: Wow, that's cool.  I guess I missed it because my search was lacking some key terms.  I looked at drupalmodules.com and on drupal.org for genealogy, gedcom, and other terms, not family tree.  An embarrassing oversight.  The 7.x branch is not recommended but I guess I should contribute to it.  Thanks for the tip...Bruce

Answer (score 0):

You'll need create a specific module (or search for an existent one) that gets the gedcom file and generates the nodes. It would be easy for the user (just one file upload).

Comment: Yes, that is what has been the issue or difficulty.  Since there are php libraries for parsing a gedcom then it would be best to use one of them, since Drupal is written in php.  So, the challenge is this: they upload their gedcom and it gets parsed into some other format, for example, csv or json, or even an RDF serialization, which gets saved.  Something has to happen to tell Drupal to now import this file.  Some kind of trigger.

Answer (score 0):

There have been some genealogy websites built on Drupal. The best one I've seen is https://ancestry.sandes.uk/, which was announced at [Functional Drupal 7 Family History Website](https://groups.drupal.org/node/534846) in the [Genealogy Discussion Group](https://groups.drupal.org/genealogy). I've launched a project to build a multi-user, multi-family-tree website on Drupal at www.greatalbum.net, based on Drupal7+OG. I discuss it [here](https://groups.drupal.org/node/534856) and [here](https://www.greatalbum.net/blog).

To be able to upload a GEDCOM file, you will need a GEDCOM module to do the work. I found this [GEDCOM Sandbox Module](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/skybow/gedcom) based on D8, but it's still very early stages, and the code is currently missing. I've contacted the author, [skybow](https://www.drupal.org/u/skybow), and he's going to restore the code. I will probably hire someone to develop the module for the GreatAlbum site, but it will be on D7 for now.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.